# Problem with Ajaxed Wordpress and internal # Links

Tags: jquery, regex, ajax, wordpress, hash

I use Ajax to load the `#article` content from the single.php into a page template where my filterable image navigation is.

the content loads fine and the filter navigation works. but when i try to copy&paste the link into a new tab the deeplinking won't work.

i figured out that the problem is the filterable navigation that filters by adding a `#foo` to the url. if i remove that function/plugin everything works.

The Ajax adds an event listner to all internal links except a few which are defined hereby:

```
 $(document).delegate("a[href^='"+siteUrl+"']:not([href*=/wp-admin/]):not([href*=/wp-login.php]):not([href$=/feed/])", "click", function() { 
    location.hash = this.pathname; 
    return false; 
 });
```

i tried adding my internal links for the filter in there, but had no success with `:not[(href^=#)]` and similiar because i don't know the logic.

i need to exclude all links from `#portfolio-filter li a`

Answer (score 0):

You could just add a class to all of the links you don't want to include, like:

$('#portfolio-filter li a').addClass('ignore');

and then work $('a[class!="ignore"]') into the selector.

Comment: sounds promising. just not sure how to get the selector to play nice with the others.. any hint?

Comment: made my way round there, but sadly this doesn't solve my problems. guess i have to refomulate my question but thanks for the answer!